# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4) when using nes_py and gym_super_mario_bros

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinforcement-learning

While running the following code

```py
from nes_py.wrappers import JoypadSpace
import gym_super_mario_bros
from gym_super_mario_bros.actions import SIMPLE_MOVEMENT
env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0')
env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)

done = True
for step in range(5000):
    if done:
        state = env.reset()
    state, reward, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    env.render()

env.close()
```

which was copied directly from the official [PyPi Doc](https://pypi.org/project/gym-super-mario-bros/)

but while running the code, i am getting the following error

```
C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py:555: UserWarning: WARN: The environment SuperMarioBros-v0 is out of date. You should consider upgrading to version `v3`.
  logger.warn(
C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gym\utils\passive_env_checker.py:195: UserWarning: WARN: The result returned by `env.reset()` was not a tuple of the form `(obs, info)`, where `obs` is a observation and `info` is a dictionary containing additional information. Actual type: `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`
  logger.warn(
C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gym\utils\passive_env_checker.py:219: DeprecationWarning: WARN: Core environment is written in old step API which returns one bool instead of two. It is recommended to rewrite the environment with new step API.
  logger.deprecation(
C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gym\utils\passive_env_checker.py:225: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool8` is a deprecated alias for `np.bool_`.  (Deprecated NumPy 1.24)
  if not isinstance(done, (bool, np.bool8)):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\SEM 6\Minor Project\super mario\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    state, reward, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
  File "C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nes_py\wrappers\joypad_space.py", line 74, in step
    return self.env.step(self._action_map[action])
  File "C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gym\wrappers\time_limit.py", line 50, in step
    observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info = self.env.step(action)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)
```

All the first warnings are okay but the last ValueError is something that I cannot get rid of.
I have tried installing previous versions of `nes_py` and `gym_super_mario_bros`. I had python version 3.10 while running it for the first time. I have even downgraded to python version 3.8.10 but still the issue persists.

If someone would be able to guide me to resolve this error then it would be very helpful to me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is some problem with `gym` itself.
I uninstalled gym with `pip uninstall gym` and then re-installed an older version - `pip install gym==0.23.1` and that fixed the error.

A big thanks to u/eleqtriq from r/learnpython. He helped me solve this error.
Here's a link to the Reddit thread - [Cannot get gym_super_mario_bros to work](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/11bafnq/cannot_get_gym_super_mario_bros_to_work/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a dependency problem with the openai/gym package. Maybe check the version of your installed openai/gym.

Comment: I have 0.26.2 version installed